# How best to implement a child property that is a list of integers

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a 1-N relationship where the child property is just a list of integers. Something like:

```
class LotteryDraw(Base):
    __tablename__ = "draw"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    draw_time: Mapped[dt.datetime]

    numbers: Mapped[List["DrawNumber"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="draw", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Draw(id={self.id!r}, draw_time={self.draw_time})"

class DrawNumber(Base):
    __tablename__ = "draw_numbers"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    number: Mapped[int]
    draw_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("draw.id"))

    draw: Mapped["LotteryDraw"] = relationship(back_populates="numbers")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.number}"

with Session(engine) as session:
    draw = LotteryDraw(
        draw_time=dt.datetime.now(),
        numbers=[DrawNumber(number=1), DrawNumber(number=39), DrawNumber(number=45), DrawNumber(number=46)],
        # I would like to be able to do this instead: numbers=[1, 39, 45, 46],
    )
    session.add_all([draw])
    session.commit()
```

As you can see, working with the `numbers` property of a LotteryDraw requires spelling out the full instantiation: `DrawNumber(number=N)`. Is it possible to pretend in my code that they are just plain integers, both for getting and setting `LotteryDraw.numbers`? (I don't mind having them as `DrawNumber`s when working just with the `draw_numbers` table directly, I'm mainly after simplifying working with LotteryDraw.)

Comment: Would it be reasonable to just add methods get_numbers and set_numbers to LotteryDraw that do what you want?

Comment: I think that would work, but probably would also need a custom constructor for LotteryDraw to handle the "numbers" named parameters? I was kind of hoping there was some setting to have SQLAlchemy do the required conversion int<->DrawNumber transparently. Hmm, maybe an [association proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) looks kind of like what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `AssociationProxy` to do this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import datetime
from typing import Annotated

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import AssociationProxy, association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.orm import (DeclarativeBase, Mapped, MappedAsDataclass,
                            mapped_column, relationship, sessionmaker)

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:test_password@localhost:5432/test_db"

engine = create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL,
    echo=True,
)
Session = sessionmaker(
    bind=engine,
)


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass


timestamp_auto = Annotated[
    datetime.datetime,
    mapped_column(
        default=datetime.datetime.now,
    ),
]


class LotteryDraw(Base):
    __tablename__ = "draw"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    draw_time: Mapped[timestamp_auto] = mapped_column(init=False)

    numbers: Mapped[list[DrawNumber]] = relationship(
        back_populates="draw",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        init=False,
        repr=False,
    )

    values: AssociationProxy[list[int]] = association_proxy(
        "numbers",
        "number",
        init=False,
    )


class DrawNumber(Base):
    __tablename__ = "draw_number"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    number: Mapped[int]
    draw_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("draw.id"), init=False)

    draw: Mapped[LotteryDraw] = relationship(
        back_populates="numbers",
        init=False,
        repr=False,
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    with Session() as session:
        draw = LotteryDraw()
        draw.values = [1, 39, 45, 46]
        session.add(draw)
        session.commit()

        print(draw)
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much @LouisHuang. Would you recommend to name the "real" field to indicate that it's an implementation detail (i.e., rename "numbers" to "_numbers") and name the virtual view to match (rename "values"->"numbers"). Or are they then too similar and end up just causing confusion?

Comment: You can always check the type hint so you won't get confused. And follow your team's naming convention if there is one.